# How do I use 3 python conditons swith 1 else

Tags: if-statement

```
if password.lower() == passx:
    print("correct")

else:
    print("wrong")

mailx = input("whats you email?")
if mailx.lower() == mail:
        print("correct")

else:
        print("wrong")

namex = input("whats you name?")
if namex.lower() == name:
    print("correct")
```

i tried using elif & and but it did not work

can you pls help me

i'm trying to make a login page in python

Comment: please help me with this i am using python feel free to judge me

Answer (score 1):

You can put your code into a login function.
With that function you can return True if all conditions are met and False as default case for at least one unmet condition.
Then check the value of the function for successfull login:

```py
def login(password, email, name):
    passx = input("whats your password?")

    if password.lower() == passx:
        mailx = input("whats you email?")

        if mailx.lower() == mail:
            namex = input("whats you name?")

            if namex.lower() == name:
                return True

    return False


if login(password, mail, name):
    print("Login successfully")
else:
    print("Login failed")
```